# Get the cursor out of span inside contenteditable

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet if the user types something after of *TEST* it automatically becomes red. This is because user typed text is going inside the `span`. While it may be the desired behaviour sometimes, often user wants to type a new word and get out of `span`.

Is there a way to toggle between the two behaviours. Ideally, I would want that if the user presses right arrow key, they should get out of `span`.

```css
.bg-red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" contenteditable="true">
     <span class="bg-red">TEST</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: In that way as you want need to do by script then.

Comment: I am fine with using JS. Can you tell me your approach?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: On right arrow use, if the cursor's at the end and there's no blank space after the last element to cursor over to, add the space and cursor over to it.

Comment: At least inline, using a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) as the spacing character forced the contenteditable to see it as a space to cursor over to. You could in theory just always have a trailing nbsp, then trim it when you call for the content.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I did that but if user deletes that nbsp, problem starts to happen again

Comment: Ok, then put it back. On delete, don't let them finish that if it's the last space.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```css
.bg-red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
     <span class="bg-red" style="float:left" contenteditable="true">TEST</span> <span contentEditable="true"  style="float:left">Your Comment</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good approach but you can't delete TEST from inside float span

Answer (score 0):

Dear  try below its simple.

```js
   
   
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('<span id="newline"> &nbsp;</span>').insertAfter('.bg-red');
            $('#wrapper').click(function () {
                if ($("#newline").length) {
                    $("#newline").focus();
                }
                else {
                  
                    $("#newline").focus();
                }

            });
            $("#wrapper").on("keypress", function () {
                $("#newline").focus();
            })
        });
```

```css
        .bg-red {
            background: red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" contenteditable="true">
        <span class="bg-red">TEST</span>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Once you delete the space, problem starts to happen again

Comment: behavior of "contenteditable" is allow to edit html in run time that why its remove span tag also.

Comment: Correct. But thats exactly the problem I am looking the solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Pure JS execution of what you requested.

1. You add an event listener to listen for keypress.
2. You identify the key you desire.
3. Execute whatever you want.

Best Wishes

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', indentifyKeyPressed);

const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");



function indentifyKeyPressed(event) {
  if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
    //Creating a new element
    const newElement = document.createElement("span")
    newElement.setAttribute("class", "bg-green")
    newElement.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
    wrapper.appendChild(newElement).focus()

  }
}
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
  <span class="bg-red" contenteditable="true" >TEST</span>
</div>
```